# Gitlab Pipelines emails Integration

Tags: gitlab

How to send a email when gitlab pipeline is triggerred. i see some configuration in gitlab under Project Settings > Integrations > Project services > Emails On Push. I have enabled this, but i dont see any email communication happenned when a pipeline is executed?

Comment: Notifications are user level settings. So in your Profile Settings, go to the notifications page and choose Watch for the relevant Group or Project.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is due to invalid SMTP email settings configured in gitlab.rb file.issue resolved after correction